# Change Windows 8 login from Live id to local account

Tags: passwords, windows-8, windows-live

Windows 8 asks for my Live login details when I login - I'd prefer to use a local password separate from my Live password. Is it possible to use a local password?

What do I lose out on if I don't use a Live account password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You lose out by not being able to Download apps or the updated content of the apps, or sync between PCs like favorites and history

- Drag your mouse to the right hand of the screen so the menu pops up
- Click Change PC Settings
- Click Users
- Under the Users Menu select Switch To A Local Account on the right hand side.
- This will prompt you to create a new local user

Answer (score 5):

Logging in with your Live account allows Windows to save a lot of your settings and some of your documents in "the cloud".  If you were to login to another Windows 8 machine some of your preferences and settings will follow you.  For instance, if you reformatted, put a new installation of Windows 8 on your computer, your preferences should take affect with the Live account.

Check this link out:  http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/06/sync-it-up-hands-on-with-the-preview-of-windows-8s-cloud-sync-service/

Answer (score 2):

Using a Microsoft account offers the following advantages:

- Settings sync between all your computers and devices with Windows 8. Windows 8 does sync a lot of settings, from your desktop theme to your File Explorer and Internet Explorer settings.
- Access to the Store to purchase and install Windows 8 apps
- The possibility to use apps such as Xbox SmartGlass that allow you to connect your Windows 8 computer to your Xbox and remote control the console.
- The possibility to fully utilize Family Safety and all its parental control & reporting features. You can use it without a Microsoft account too but you won't have access to all its features without one.

If it annoys you that you have to introduce along password every time, you can set a PIN or a Picture Password to make the log in procedure faster. More information about all the available sign in options can be found here: [Introducing Windows 8: How to Switch Between Sign-In Options](http://www.7tutorials.com/introducing-windows-8-how-switch-between-sign-options).

If you still want to go ahead and switch to a local account, from a Microsoft account, you can find a full step by step procedure here: [How to Switch to a Local Account from a Microsoft Account in Windows 8](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-switch-local-account-microsoft-account-windows-8)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a 4-digit pin for quick log in.

- Drag your mouse to the right hand of the screen so the menu pops up, Click Settings
- Click Change PC Settings at the bottom
- Click Users. You will see a "Create a PIN" button on the right

You won't lose out anything with the benefits of using a Live account because essentially it just creates a 4-digit pin for easy access.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't answer my question of _What do I lose out on if I don't use a Live account password?_

Comment: @Sathya I've updated my answer but a downvote, seriously?

Comment: Downvote because the answer isn't useful. (hover on the tooltip). Also, answer's incorrect. (look at the other answers)