# how to remove an email account from windows 8 pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Windows 8 login from Live id to local account](https://superuser.com/questions/466803/change-windows-8-login-from-live-id-to-local-account)
>   [How to remove an account from Mail app in windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/493904/how-to-remove-an-account-from-mail-app-in-windows-8)

I'm new to windows 8 pro so just tried to add my hotmail account to it and it worked fine. Now, trying to remove my account but there is no such friendly way to do this!

In http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-or-remove-a-Windows-Mail-account
author has described controls or All Program option which I'm not able to see here.

```
To remove a Windows Mail account

    Open Windows Mail by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking All Programs, and then clicking Windows Mail.

    Click the Tools menu, and then click Accounts.
    Click the account you want to remove, and then click Remove.
```

Where is Tools menu? or ... rest of it?

Can somebody walk me through this?

Thanks,
ak

Comment: See [How to remove an account from Mail app in windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/493904/how-to-remove-an-account-from-mail-app-in-windows-8) and [Change Windows 8 login from Live id to local account](http://superuser.com/questions/466803/change-windows-8-login-from-live-id-to-local-account).

Answer (score 2):

To remove a acount from the windows mail app:
Open the charm bar by swiping from the right edge -> Settings -> Account

To switch your win 8 to a local account: Click on your username in the upper right corner -> Change account picture -> select Users (right) -> Switch to local account